# evaluate symbolic expression over meshgrind in python

Tags: python, eval, sympy, mesh

I would like to evaluate a symbolic expression over a meshgrid. My testcode is the following:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')
test = sym.gamma(x)/sym.sqrt(y)

X = np.linspace( start = 1, stop = 2)
Y = np.linspace( start = 4, stop = 7)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = test.evalf(subs = {x : X, y: Y})
```

It seems that python tries to create an object with many many dimensions, which is totally not what I have in mind. Is there a way to do this without loops over the function arguments?

Best

Answer (score 1):

As you are interested in numerical evaluations, use of sympy does not offer you any advantage compared to numpy/scipy whose functions can also be applied to all elements of an `ndarray` via a single call.

```
from scipy.special import gamma
from numpy import sqrt

test = lambda x, y: gamma(x)/sqrt(y)

Z = text(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
This was just a simple example. I guess, I need the sympi package since the expressions that will be evaluated are rather long and rearranged before evaluating. 
Using the lambda function from above does produce the same error as before.

Comment: @Daniel If you are restricted to sympy, then what you are trying to do makes no sense (to sympy!) as `x` is declared as a (scalar) symbol and you try to substitute it with a numpy matrix. You must use a `for` loop to go through each pair of elements of `X`, `Y` and evaluate the expression. Another approach  you might want to try is to use `sympy.lambdify` to convert the sympy expression to a numpy expression.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest lambdifying the sympy function and then vectorizing before evauating, as below:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')
test = sym.gamma(x)/sym.sqrt(y)

X = np.linspace( start = 1, stop = 2)
Y = np.linspace( start = 4, stop = 7)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Lambdfy and vectorize symbolic test function
fxy = np.vectorize(lambdify([x, y], test))

# Evaluate Z in meshgrid
Z = fxy(X,Y)

# Plot scaled funtion (Multiplyed by SCALE of 10)
SCALE = 10
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, SCALE*Z)
# Set an equal aspect ratio
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title('Scaled Gama Square Root Ratio Function')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('10*Z')
plt.show()
```